# C# emulate/create internal network drive

Tags: c#

I want to emulate/create network drive.
The idea is to have beneath this network drive other mapped drives for which end users are not aware (do not have to mapped them by them selves and sec. reasons of course). Hence every end user will have only one network drive visible in his inner network and will not have to mount everything else by his own.
At this point i could not manage to find how can i emulate/create such network drive either via examples or checking Network API, etc.
I would appreciate any guidelines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Rendeto, welcome to stackoverflow. This is a Q&A site where we can help you with *specific* programming questions. What have you done so far? Do you have any specific code that you need help with? Editing your question with this will help you get a good answer.

Comment: Hello Tobbe, I do not have any code, regarding creating such internal network drive. Mapping shares is easy ( via http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetUseAdd.html for example), but i need to emulate a network drive under which i can add(mount) these shares. I assume that may be I will need some driver implementation as well for CIFS compliant programmatically created network driver, but this just my assumption. Also may be C++ could be better option here, but i am not sure. Any guideline in this direction would be appreciated due to limited experience i have in c++/C# word.